# Adding new items to an array causes exisiting items to get deleted. This happens online, but not locally. Why?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a table that gets populated with data from a database.

To allow the user to only view the data they wish to see, I have added a filter to the table which gets triggered by a group of checkboxes. When a checkbox is not checked, then specific data will not be shown.
For example, you want to see a name? Then you check the checkbox for "name". You also want to see status? Then you check the checkbox for status.
This action is saved using Local Storage

This works perfectly fine when I run the code on my localhost, but as soon as I put the code up online I'm only allowed to have one checkbox checked at a time. If I check a second checkbox, then then first checkbox gets unchecked.

I don't understand this behaviour. Why can I check multiple checkboxes locally, but not online?

This is what it looks like locally:
[image]

And this is what it looks like online:
[image]

It seems like when I run the code online it does not register it as an array at all.

This is the code:

```html
<template>

          <b-row class="d-none d-sm-block" v-if="selectedPropertyId && tableLayout">
            <b-col class="mb-3">
              <b-form-checkbox-group inline v-model="selectedFieldKeys" :options="selectableFields" text-field="label" value-field="key" />
            </b-col>
          </b-row>

        <b-row class="d-sm-none" v-if="selectedPropertyId && tableLayout">
          <b-col class="mb-3">
            <b-form-checkbox-group stacked v-model="selectedFieldKeys" :options="selectableFields" text-field="label" value-field="key" />
          </b-col>
        </b-row>

          <b-table
            v-if="selectedPropertyId && tableLayout"
            :items="units"
            :fields="fields"
            :filter="filterList"
            striped
            :empty-text="$t('emptyText')"
            :empty-filtered-text="$t('emptyFilteredText')"
            search-placeholder="searchInList"
            :per-page="[500, 1000]"
            sort-by="unitName"
            primary-key="dummyId"
            small="small"
            foot-clone
            clear-foot-clone
            no-footer-sorting
            sticky-header="67vh"
            include-filter
          />

        </template>
        
        <script>
  import moment from 'moment';
  import LoadingMessage from '@/components/LoadingMessage';
  import {listService} from '@/services/lists';
  import {propertyService} from '@/services/property';

  const localStorageKeyName = 'visibleFieldNames';

  export default {

    data() {
      return {
        selectedFieldKeys: [],
        selectedPropertyId: null,
        loadingList: false,
        properties: [],
        units: null,
        allUnits: null
      };
    },
    props: {
      initialPropertyId: {
        type: String,
        default: null
      }
    },
    methods: {
      load() {
        propertyService.list()
          .then(result => this.properties = result.data)
          .catch(error => console.error(error));
      },

      getList() {
        if (this.selectedPropertyId) {
          this.units = null;
          this.allUnits = null;
          this.loadingList = true;
          const propertyId = this.selectedPropertyId === 'all' ? null : this.selectedPropertyId;
          listService.rentalListReport(propertyId)
            .then(result => {
              this.units = result.data;
              this.allUnits = this.units;

              this.loadingList = false;
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.error(error);
              this.loadingList = false;
            });
        }
      },
      normalColumn(key, label) {
        return {
          key,
          label: this.$t(label ?? key),
          sortable: true
        };
      },
      enumColumn(key, prefix, label) {
        return Object.assign(this.normalColumn(key, label), {
          formatter: value => value && this.$t(`${prefix}.${value}`),
          sortByFormatted: true
        });
      },
      numberColumn(key, label) {
        return Object.assign(this.normalColumn(key, label), {
          template: {
            type: 'number',
            format: {
              minimumFractionDigits: '2',
              maximumFractionDigits: '2'
            },
            foot: sum
          }
        });
      },
      dateColumn(key, label) {
        return Object.assign(this.normalColumn(key, label), {
          template: {type: 'date', format: 'L'}
        });
      }
    },
    computed: {
      selectableFields() {
        return [
          {
            key: 'unitName',
            label: this.$t('unit'),
            sortable: true,
            template: {
              type: 'link',
              label: data => data.item.unitName,
              to: data => `/units/${data.item.unitId}`,
              foot: count
            }
          },
          this.normalColumn('stageName', 'stage'),
          this.normalColumn('unitNumber'),
          this.enumColumn('status', 'model.unit.status'),
          this.normalColumn('numberWaitingList', 'waitingList'),
          this.normalColumn('reserved'),
          this.enumColumn('unitType', 'model.unit.types', 'type'),
          this.normalColumn('internalType'),
          this.dateColumn('availableDate'),
          this.dateColumn('rentEndDate'),
          this.numberColumn('privateArea', 'model.unit.fields.PRIVATE_AREA'),
          this.numberColumn('commercialArea', 'model.unit.fields.COMMERCIAL_AREA'),
          this.numberColumn('numberRooms', 'model.unit.fields.NUMBER_ROOMS'),
          this.enumColumn('rentalPeriod', 'model.rentalPeriod'),
          this.numberColumn('rentOnAvailableDate', 'rentWithoutVat'),
          this.numberColumn('rentVatOnAvailableDate', 'rentVat'),
          this.numberColumn('rentPerYearPerM2OnAvailableDate', 'rentPerYearPerM2WithoutVat'),
          this.numberColumn('rentPerYearPerM2VatOnAvailableDate', 'rentPerYearPerM2WithVat'),
          this.numberColumn('depositOnAvailableDate', 'depositWithoutVat'),
          this.numberColumn('depositVatOnAvailableDate', 'depositWithVat'),
          this.numberColumn('prepaymentOnAvailableDate', 'prepaymentWithoutVat'),
          this.numberColumn('prepaymentVatOnAvailableDate', 'prepaymentWithVat'),
          this.numberColumn('acontoOnAvailableDate', 'acontoWithoutVat'),
          this.numberColumn('acontoVatOnAvailableDate','acontoWithVat'),
        ];
      },
      fields() {
          return this.selectableFields.filter(field => this.selectedFieldKeys?.includes(field.key)).concat(
            {
              key: 'unitUnavailable',
              label: '',
              sortable: true,
              template: {
                type: 'status'
              }
            },
            {
              key: 'actions',
              template: {
                type: 'actions',
                head: [
                  {
                    type: 'export'
                  }
                ],
                cell: this.actions
              }
            }
          )
        }
      },


    created() {
      this.selectedPropertyId = this.initialPropertyId;
      try {
        this.selectedFieldKeys = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(localStorageKeyName));
      } catch {
        this.selectedFieldKeys = this.selectableFields.map(field => field.key);
      }
    },
    watch: {
      selectedPropertyId: 'getList',
      selectedFieldKeys: {
        deep: true,
        handler() {
          window.localStorage.setItem(localStorageKeyName, JSON.stringify(this.selectedFieldKeys));
        }
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: have you checked your local storage online to see if it is working

Comment: Yes. The main difference is that on Localhost, I can populate the list with multiple items, which are saved on local storage. Online it only allows me to store ONE item in the list.